# How to split a String on the basis of comma

Tags: java, regex, string

I am having a String which is a combination of comma and space now to want to get specific elements in a order How i can do that ,I am posting the String

```
12:00am, 2:30am3:30am, 5:00am7:45pm,9:00pm
```

This is the String i am trying to split the String using

```
List<String> interviewTimingToFrom1 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime1.split(","));
```

But this is not working ,i just want to split 12:00am,3:30am,7:45pm in a List and 2:30am,5:00am,9:00am  in a list  how to do that ,please somebody help

Comment: What exactly are your requirements?

Comment: @MarounMaroun want to split 12:00am,3:30am,7:45pm in a List and 2:30am,5:00am,9:00am in a list

Comment: well the thing is... Your string doesn't have proper formatting. Why are there random missing commas? And how will a normal regex splitting operation determine where to cut your list into those two lists? Please explain.

Comment: So you want them in two separate lists? What is the condition determining which substring goes where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
List<String> interviewTimingToFrom1 = Arrays.asList(
                    interviewTime1.split("\\s*,\\s*|(?<=[ap]m)(?=\\d)"));
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC5lY2/2)

**RegEx Breakup**

Split using:

```
\s*,\s*          # comma surrounded by optional spaces on either sides
|                # regex alternation
(?<=[ap]m)(?=\d) # when preceding text is am or pm and following character is a digit
```

Comment: @anubhava not working it is not able to split the String

Comment: @AndyBrown so obviously not a link-only answer. Look at all that stuff around the link :O

Comment: Actually, yes I see your point. The regex by itself didn't teach the user what the it does, and the link may die; then this answer loses a lot of value.

Comment: @anubhava your answer was write but wanted it to be inserted in two seperate lists